# Operator theory problem

Tags: operator-theory

Show that operator $ T : C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])  $, where

$$ Ty(t) = \int_{0}^{1} |x-t|^{-1/2}y(x) \ dx. $$

Calculate the norm T.

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: supposing that the norm in $C([0,1])$ is the $\sup$ norm,
$$
|Ty(t)| = \left|\int_0^1|x-t|^{-1/2}y(x)\,dx\right|\le
\int_0^1|x-t|^{-1/2}|y(x)|\,dx\le \|y\|\int_0^1|x-t|^{-1/2}\,dx = \cdots
$$